# Pasar un valor GET por JSON

Tags: php, mysql, json, get

Hola estoy empezando apenas en esto y tengo la siguiente duda y espero no sea lo mas obvia o incongruente...

La formulo de la siguiente manera, actualmente genero una tabla en **PHP** con una consulta en **SQL** donde en ella uso un valor obtenido por **"GET"** y otro por una **variable** que defino tambien yo, la consulta es la siguiente.

```
SELECT * FROM
  psb_smt.psb_produccion psb
INNER JOIN
  psb_smt.psb_hours psb2 ON psb.psb_hr = psb2.id_desc
WHERE 
  psb_line='".$_GET['line']."' AND psb.id_psbinfo='".$idPSB."'
ORDER BY description ASC
```

Hasta ahi todo funciona bien, lo que pasa es que ahora esa tabla la quiero generar de otra forma por **JSON**, entonces me cree un nuevo archivo **tablaprod.php** donde en ella almaceno la consulta y el **array**, despues lo muestro en la tabla de la siguiente manera.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  var url="tablaprod.php";
  $("#tablajson tbody").html("");
    $.getJSON(url,function(clientes){
      $.each(clientes, function(i,cliente){
  var newRow =
  "<tr>"
    +"<td>"+cliente.psb_line+"</td>"
    +"<td>"+cliente.psb_hr+"</td>"
    +"<td>"+cliente.psb_np+"</td>"
    +"<td>"+cliente.psb_model+"</td>"
    +"</tr>";
  $(newRow).appendTo("#tablajson tbody");
      });
    });
  });
```

Todo funciona correctamente si yo en la consulta defino los valores, pero si yo pongo la consulta con **GET** y con la variable no me funciona la tabla.

Este es mi archivo tablaprod.php
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: A simple vista no veo problema en el código; podrías indicar cúal es el resultado de ese script.? es decir que imprime el $json_string? eso puedes verlo en la herramienta de red de tu navegador o ejecutando el script directamente.

Comment: En caso de estar seguro que ese Query retorne datos te sugiero valida que la funcion json_encode no se este topandoo con caracteres que no puede procesar, en esos casos la funcion retorna vacío, y lo que debes hacer es aplicar el encoding correcto a tus datos, prueba utf8_encode al obtener los valores de $row.

Comment: [{"description":"06:40 - 07:00","psb_hr":"04","psb_np":"28572072","psb_model":"Allison"}

Si me genera el array cuando yo defino los datos en la consulta, pero cuando yo pongo en mi consulta de SQL el dato con GET ya no me devuelve nada...

Comment: He tenido algunas veces ese problema, si la consulta efectivamente trae datos; revisa los datos que tienes en la tabla y si tienen acentos o caracteres especiales, si ese es el caso y es la razón por la cual json_encode trae datos en blanco usa utf8_encode al obtener los valores de $row.

Comment: Encontre el problema al parecer... a ver si me pueden ayudar la consulta funciona si hago esto
URL.com/tablaprod.php?line=Linea%2006
Pero esa no es la URL que yo cargo, la mia es
http://URL.com/lineAll.php?line=Linea%2006 y aqui no funciona que puedo hacer?

Comment: Tú tienes declarado esto como URL: `var url="tablaprod.php";` si se llama de otro modo, debes indicarlo ahí en esa variable, haciendo: `var url="lineAll.php";` pues la llamada va dirigida a lo que pasas en la variable `url` aquí: `$.getJSON(url,function(clientes){`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Amigo, por el momento veo dos inconsistencias:

1. El query necesita de las variables $_GET['line'] y $idPSB para ejecutarse, sin embargo no veo de donde se obtiene el valor de $idPSB. Para solucionar este inconveniente puedes capturar el valor por parámetro GET como lo estas haciendo con 'line', osea $_GET['idPSB'].
2. Estas usando la función getJSON de JQuery, sin embargo no veo que le estés enviando los parámetros que necesitas, desde el front. Para solucionar este inconveniente puedes probar alguna de las siguientes alternativas:

2.1 Pasar los parámetros como un objeto:

```
...
var url="tablaprod.php";
var params = {
    line: 'REEMPLAZA_EL_VALOR_CORRESPONDIENTE',
    idPSB: 'REEMPLAZA_EL_VALOR_CORRESPONDIENTE'
};
$.getJSON(url, params, function(dataVal) {
...
```

2.2 Pasar los parámetros por la url:

```
...
var url="tablaprod.php?line=REEMPLAZA_EL_VALOR_CORRESPONDIENTE&idPSB=REEMPLAZA_EL_VALOR_CORRESPONDIENTE";
$.getJSON(url, function(dataVal) {
...
```

Comment: Me funciono lo hice asi
  var url="tablaprod.php";
  var params = {
    line: '<?php echo $_GET['line'] ?>',
    idPSB: '<?php echo $idPSB ?>'
  };